# Given non-negative integers such that $12^a \cdot 324^b \cdot 48^c $ is divisible by $ 6^{70} $. Find the smallest possible $ a + b + c $.

Tags: number-theory

Given non-negative integers such that $12^a \cdot 324^b \cdot 48^c $ is divisible by $ 6^{70} $. Find the smallest possible $ a + b + c $.

First I can make an assumption that $a+b+c$ will be the smallest if we can obtain the highest power of b, then c and later a.

Let me go in the general way, $12^a\cdot 324^b\cdot48^c$ = $ 3^a \cdot  2^{2a} \cdot 3^{4b} \cdot 2^{2b} \cdot3^c \cdot 2^{4c}$ = $3^{a+4b+c} \cdot 2^{2a+2b+4c}$

And $6^{70}$ = $2^{70}\cdot 3^{70}$

Then I need to find the solution for $a+4b+c = 70$ and $a+b+2c=35$ where a+b+c need to be the samllest.

Please anyone can show me the solution how to approach this type of questions.

Comment: You don't need $a+4b +c =70$ and $a + b +2c =35$.  You only need $a+4b+c \ge 70$ and $a+b+2c \ge 35$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(2^2 3\right)^a \cdot \left(2^2 3^4\right)^b \cdot \left(2^4 3\right)^c=3^{a+4 b+c} \cdot2^{2 a+2 b+4 c}$$
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b+c \text{ is minimum}\\
a+4b+c=70\\
2a+2b+4c=70\\
\end{cases}
$$
From second and third equations we get
$$
\begin{cases}
4b+c=70-a&\to -4b-c=-70+a\\
2b+4c=70-2a&\to 4b+8c=140-4a\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$7c=70-3a\to c=\frac{70-3a}{7}$$
and finally
$$b= 15-\frac{a}{7},c= 10-\frac{3 a}{7}$$

**edit**

```
(thanks to @TonyK for correcting)
```

which are integer for $a=0$, therefore the minimum value is $a+b+c=25$ when
$$a=0,b=15,c=10.$$

Comment: I am sorry, this solution seems wrong.

Comment: @user376343 Where is the mistake?

Comment: @user376343 Maybe you could give a hint what is off? I do not see the problem :)

Comment: You didn't see that $b$ and $c$ are integers for $a=0$ as well as $a=7$.

Comment: You want to minimize $a+b+c$. So plugging in the expressions you found, you want to minimize
$$a+(15-\tfrac 17a)+(10-\tfrac37a)=\tfrac37a+25.$$
Given that $a$ is nonnegative, this is minimal for $a=0$.

Comment: @TonyK Right! OP says NON-negative. I missed that

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A=12^a \cdot 324^b \cdot 48^c.$

From $$12^a \cdot 324^b \cdot 48^c=6^a2^a6^{2b}3^{2b}6^c2^{3c}$$ we see that the best strategy is to take $b$ as large as possible, because the steps of $b$ are twice those of $a$ or $c.$

Further, note that each $324^b$ offers $3^2$ extra that we need to join to some remaining $2s$ from $2^a$ or $2^{3c}.$
Clearly, $2^{3c}$ is the best choice, because a single $c$ offers $2^3.$

Let us start with $(a,b,c)=(0,35,0),$ here $A=6^{70}3^{70}$ and $a+b+c=35.$

Note that $(0,33,1)$ gives $A=6^{70}3^{63}$ and $a+b+c=34.$

In general, $(a,b,c)=(0,35-2k,k)$ gives $A=6^{70-4k}3^{70-4k}6^k2^{3k}$ or
$$A=6^{70-3k}3^{70-4k}2^{3k}$$

To obtain $A$ divisible by $6^{70},$ solve $$70-4k=3k.$$

We obtain $k=10,$ the triple is $(a,b,c)=(0,15,10)$ and the sum $$a+b+c=0+15+10=25.$$

Answer (score 1):

We need $a+4b+c \ge 70$ and $a+b+2c \ge 35$.

Let's suppose we have $\alpha + 4\beta + \gamma \ge 70$ and $\alpha + \beta + 2\gamma \ge 35$ and $\alpha +\beta + \gamma = k$.

But then $\alpha - 1 + 4(\beta +1) +\gamma\ge  73>70$ and $\alpha -1 +(\beta + 1) + 2\gamma \ge 35$ annd $(\alpha -1) + (\beta + 1) + \gamma = k$.

So wolog we may assume $a = 0$.  (If we have a small value for $a,b,c$ with $a \ge 1$ it can't hurt to replace decrease $a$ and increase $b$ if necessary)

So if $a = 0$ we need $b \ge \frac {70-c}4$ and $c \ge \frac {35-b}2$.

If we replace $b = 17-x$ and $c=17-y$ we get

$68 - 4x + 17 -y \ge 70$ or $4x+y \le 15$ and $17-x + 34-2y\ge 35$ or $x+2y\le 16$.

To get as close to these values as possible we can, if we solve for equality we get $x=2; y=7$ so

$a = 0; b= 15; c =10$ is as solution with $a+4b + c =70$ and $a+b+2c = 35$.  And $a+b +c =25$ is pretty small.

And it's easy to see that is an absolute minimum.  We can't decrease $a$ at all.  We can't decrease $b$ without increasing $a$ or $c$ four times as much to maintain $a + 4b + c \ge 70$.  And we can't decrease $c$ without increasing $a$ or $b$ twice as much to maintain $a + b = 2c \ge 35$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way** .

We have $$ 2^{2 a+2 b+4 c}*3^{a+4 b+c} =6^{70}M$$ A minimum possible is when
$$2a+2b+4c=a+4b+c=70\Rightarrow a-2b+3c=0$$ whose integers solutions are given by $$(a,b,c)=(a,2a+3n,a+2n)$$ where $a$ is take as parameter and $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Now $$a+b+c=a+4(2a+3n)+(a+2n)=10a+14n=70$$
In the  expression $10a+14n$ we can choose searching for a minimum with non-negative integers $n=0$ and $a=0$. An easy calculation gives for $n=0$ the sum $a+b+c=28$ and for $a=0$ we have $$10a+14n=14n=70\iff n=5$$ from which$$a+b+c=0+3\cdot5+2\cdot5=25$$Thus $a+b+c=25$ is the required minimum.